# Alineando a la derecha una celda dependiendo de la alineacion que tenga su header con iTextSharp

Tags: itextsharp

Estoy creando un pdf a partir de un gridview usando las clases PdfPTable y PdfPCell de iTextSharp 5.5.11 y tengo varias columnas como Costo y Precio entre otras, pero en el caso particualr de estas dos quisiera me muestren su contenido alineado a la derecha.

```
    If gridViewHeaderCell.Text = "Cost" Or gridViewHeaderCell.Text = "Price" 
        Or gridViewHeaderCell.Text = "Profit" Or gridViewHeaderCell.Text = 
        "Total Cost" Or gridViewHeaderCell.Text = "Total Billed" Or 
        gridViewHeaderCell.Text = "Total Profit" Then     
            pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT               
    End If
```

con este codigo lo logro para los encabezados pero necesito hacerlo para las celdas de cada una de estas columnas tambien.

Alguien sabe alguna forma de antes de adicionar la celda saber a cual encabezado(columna) pertenece?

Comment: Como estas agregando las celdas que no son encabezado? con el indice y con el nombre de la columna, debe haber una propiedad del gridView que te diga es información, en que estas programando? windowsForm? asp.net??

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme, estoy programando en asp.net vb, pero ya resolvi el problema. Lo que hice fue auxiliarme de una variable count que controla la posicion de la celda en la row y asi decido si quiero esa celda alineada a la derecha o a la izquierda.

Comment: Excelente :-) muy bien (Y)